# How to show NULL records in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I got simple database with 3 tables :

```
Galaxy(GalaxyID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT);

Planet(PlanetID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, GalaxyID INTEGER, Name TEXT, Population INTEGER);

Continent(ContinentID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, PlanetID INTEGER,Name TEXT);

INSERT INTO Galaxy VALUES 
(1, "MILKY WAY"),
(2, "IC 1101"),
(3, "GN-z11");

INSERT INTO Planet VALUES 
(1,1, "Earth", 100000),
(2,1, "Moon", 0),
(3,1, "Saturn", 0),
(4,2, "IC-123", 0),
(5,2, "IC-124", 1),
(6,2, "IC-126", 4),
(7,3, "GN-24", 1),
(8,3, "GN-26", 1),
(9,3, "GN-28", 4);

INSERT INTO Continent VALUES 
(1,1, "Europe"),
(2,4, "UnnamedContinent1"),
(3,4, "UnnamedContinent2");
```

I want to select Galaxy which dont have Continent at all:

```
SELECT Galaxy.Name, Planet.name
FROM Galaxy
LEFT OUTER JOIN Planet, Continent
ON Continent.PlanetID = Planet.PlanetID AND Galaxy.GalaxyID = Planet.GalaxyID
GROUP BY Galaxy.Name
HAVING COUNT(ContinentID) IS NULL
```

This Query wont work but if i give HAVING COUNT(ContinentID) IS NOT NULL it will appers all Galaxy with Continents(IC 1101 and MILKY WAY) 
How to show NULL record like: GN-z11 NULL

Comment: `COUNT(Column)` will not return with `NULL`, it will return with 0 when there are only records with `NULL` in the column. You can use a where condition to reach your goal: `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Continent WHERE Planet.PlanetID = Continent.PlanetID)`

Answer (score 1):

No need for `COUNT`, nor `having`, nor `group by`, just add extra left join with `continent` table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT g.Name GalaxyName, p.name PlanetName
FROM Galaxy AS g
LEFT JOIN Planet AS p ON g.GalaxyID = p.GalaxyID
LEFT JOIN Continent AS c ON c.PlanetID = p.PlanetID 
WHERE c.PlanetID IS NULL;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5f59/4)

Comment: Thanks for reply! But the result is all Galaxy with Planet without Continent and i want to have a Galaxy without Continent at all Planets

Answer (score 0):

First, `COUNT()` never returns `NULL`.  It returns `0` if there are no matching rows.

Second, do not use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

And then table aliases make the query easier to write and read.

Finally, you just need a `WHERE` clause and no aggregation:

```
SELECT g.Name
FROM Galaxy g LEFT JOIN
     Planet p 
     USING (GalaxyID) LEFT JOIN
     Continent c
     USING (PlanetID) 
WHERE c.PlanetId IS NULL;
```

Now, this may seem like it is doing the right thing.  However, a galaxy is going to be listed for every planet that doesn't have a continent.  The quick-and-dirty fix is to use `SELECT DISTINCT` rather than `SELECT`.

A better overall method is to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT g.*
FROM Galaxy g
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Planet p JOIN
                       Continent c
                       USING (PlanetID) 
                  WHERE p.GalaxyID = g.GalaxyID
                 );
```

Comment: Hello! Yes your right the galaxy is going to be listed for every planet that doesn't have a continent and SELECT DISTINCT wont fixing it. I try the NOT EXISTS method but it doesnt work well either

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this way:

```
SELECT Galaxy.Name, Planet.name
FROM Galaxy
LEFT join Planet P ON  Galaxy.GalaxyID = Planet.GalaxyID
where not exists 
    (select *
     from Continent as C
     where C.PlanetID=P.PlanetID)
```